# Storing R.id.elements in XML resources

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I have layout with several EditText elements:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/etName"/>
<EditText android:id="@+id/etModel"/>
<EditText android:id="@+id/etYear"/>
```

And this array stores ID's of all these elements:

```
int[] fields = {
     R.id.etName,
     R.id.etModel,
     R.id.etYear
};
```

Can I store and load these ID's in "res/values/fields.xml" instead int array in java file like this:

```
<resources>
    <array name="fields">
        <item name="etName" type="id" />
        <item name="etModel" type="id" />
        <item name="etYear" type="id" />
    </array>
</resources>


TypedArray fields = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.fields);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ids already exist in your xml layout, you can simply refer to them to define an array:

```
<array name="fields">
    <item>@id/etName</item>
    <item>@id/etModel</item>
    <item>@id/etYear</item>
</array>
```

After then you can use this array in your code:

```
TypedArray fields = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.fields);
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length(); i++) {
    EditText editText = findViewById(fields.getResourceId(i, 0));
    editText.setText("Yo!"); // or something else
}
fields.recycle();
```